# Control thread to exit haskell application

Tags: haskell, concurrency, asynchronous, io

I'm brand new to Haskell and in messing around with a few samples I've got a problem where I can't stop the program. I'm using Windows 7 and using runhaskell from ght. Ctrl-c doesn't work so I have to resort to the task manager which is a bit of a pain.

Instead of doing that how can I create a separate control thread that would wait until I typed q and then quit my Haskell application.

The application I've got the problem with is of the format:

```
main = do
 h <- connectTo server (PortNumber (fromInteger port))
 hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
 ... do some stuff with the socket handle ...
 listen h

listen :: Handle -> IO ()
listen h = forever $ do
  t <- hGetLine h
  let s = init t
  putStrLn s
where
  forever a = do a; forever a
```

In pseudo-code what I'd like to have is:

```
main = do
  waitForQuit
  ... original program ...

waitForQuit :: IO()
   option <- getChar
   if option == 'q' then
     ... kill the app ... 
   else 
     waitForQuit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a Haskell thread, getChar and exit{With,Success,Failure}.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Exit
import Data.Char (toLower)
import System.IO

main = do
    forkIO realMain
    exitOnQ

exitOnQ = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    c <- getChar
    when (toLower c /= 'q') exitOnQ
    exitSuccess  -- or "exitWith" and some ExitCode value, use hoogle.
```

Breaking this down: You get concurrently via `forkIO`.  Notice this isn't a separate OS thread, but a Haskell thread which is extremely lightweight.  The `exitOnQ` thread needs to get keystrokes without delay - without the `NoBuffering` you'd have to hit q-[ENTER].  If the pressed key wasn't `q` (or `Q`) then we loop, otherwise we terminate the program via one of the many `exit*` calls.

WARNING: It is a very uncommon corner case, but GHC uses GC points as thread scheduling points (has this changed in the past two years?) so if your code is spending significant blocks of time performing lots of pure computations that have zero allocation then you can't use this method to quit (unless you have multiple OS threads via the threaded RTS *and* an `+RTS -N#` option).

Comment: The program only quits when the main thread exits, so you need to exchange `...` and `exitOnQ`. Do the work in the extra thread, the `exitWith`'ing  in the main.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I create a separate control thread that would wait until I typed q and then quit my Haskell application.

You can create new threads with `forkIO`, which takes a chunk of code as an argument. E.g.

```
main = do
    forkIO waitForQuit
    ....
```

The quit handler will spend most of its time blocked on `getChar`, but when it wakes up, it can terminate the program, by throwing an exit exception, such as:

```
    exitWith ExitSuccess
```

You may need to compile the program with `ghc -O -threaded` to ensure the program main thread can make progress, while the handler is waiting on `q`

Comment: This will not work, calling exitWith from a thread will only kill that thread.